# What DC should a Skeleton's Explosive Death ability be?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e

**What DC should a Skeleton's Explosive Death ability be?** I've just been using the standard DC for a level equal to the skeleton, which is fine for the [Skeletal Champion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=373) but that poses some problems for the [Skeleton Guard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=372) (which is level -1). The Bestiary (at least, Bestiary 1, the only one I have) doesn't seem to offer guidance on this, but I could be missing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The GM Picks

The rules for basic saves and DCs are in the Core Rulebook. Pg. 503 says:

> "As the Game Master, it's up to you to set the difficulty classes (DCs) for checks that don't use a predefined DC.

The rules for *Explosive Death* don't include a DC, so it's the GM's role to decide what the DC should be. That means there is no single numerical answer that is correct.

The rest of that section describes a variety of different ways that may help you decide what the DC could be. None of these are authoritative, both are merely guidance for ways a GM could decide. No matter which method you use (if any) you can always adjust the DC for circumstances, perhaps by using the DC Adjustments table on pg. 504 or merely your own discretion.

### Simple DCs

Simple DCs assign a DC based on the degree of training the GM thinks is appropriate for the task. These tend to be easiest with skill checks (in my opinion), but I sometimes use them when I need to quickly set a DC in combat without worrying about the details.

The GM will subjectively determine whether the task is best described as untrained, trained, expert, et cet. and then pick the DC they want from the table.

### DCs by Level

DCs may also be assigned by level. This seems to be the method you have been using, but the difficulty is that there is no entry in the table for level -1. One potential solution would be to extend the table to include level -1, which could result in a DC of 13.